# How do I advertise additional routes into an existing BGP peer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-vpc

I'm trying to get my private ip address ranges my cloudsql instance is using routable across my vpn: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip#vpn

I need to run this command:

```
gcloud compute routers update my-router \
    --advertisement-mode custom \
    --set-advertisement-groups all_subnets \
    --set-advertisement-ranges 1.2.3.4,6.7.0.0/16
```

The closest resource I can find for this is google_compute_router_peer but I already have a peer configured with an advertise_mode of DEFAULT with aws VPN endpoints

Can I have multiple google_compute_router_peers for the same router and peer with different advertise_modes?

```
resource "google_compute_router_peer" "peer" {
  name                      = "my-router-peer"
  router                    = "my-router"

  // I already have a peer configured for the same router, peer ip address, asn, etc. 
  // Its configured with as DEFAULT advertise mode and is used to create a VPN with AWS VPN gateways
  advertise_mode            = "custom"
  advertised_groups         = [all_subnets]
 
  advertised_ip_ranges {
    range = ["1.2.3.4"]
  }
  advertised_ip_ranges {
    range = ["6.7.0.0/16"]
  }

  peer_ip_address           = "169.254.1.2"
  peer_asn                  = 65513
  advertised_route_priority = 100
  interface                 = "interface-1"
}
```

FYI I know I can shell out to local-exec to run arbitrary commands- I am of course trying to avoid that.